# java.util.NoSuchElementException using iterator in java

Tags: java, iterator, nosuchelementexception

I'm trying to iterate through a list using the iterator over my list of Logs. The goal is to search for a logs which contains the same phonenumber, type and date as the new log

However, I get a java.util.NoSuchElementException in my conditional statement. Does anyone know what might cause the problem?

My code

```
public void addLog(String phonenumber, String type, long date, int incoming, int outgoing)
{
    //Check if log exists or else create it.
    Log newLog = new Log(phonenumber, type, date, incoming, outgoing);

    //Log exists
    Boolean notExist = false;

    //Iterator loop
    Iterator<Log> iterator = logs.iterator();


    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        //This is where get the exception
        if (iterator.next().getPhonenumber() == phonenumber  && iterator.next().getType() == type && iterator.next().getDate() == date)
        {

            updateLog(newLog, iterator.next().getId());
        }
        else
        {   
            notExist = true;
        }

    }

    if (notExist)
    {
        logs.add(newLog);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You are calling `next()` a bunch of times in one iteration forcing the `Iterator` to move to an element that doesn't exist.

Instead of

```
if (iterator.next().getPhonenumber() == phonenumber  && iterator.next().getType() == type && iterator.next().getDate() == date)
{
    updateLog(newLog, iterator.next().getId());
    ...
```

Use

```
Log log = iterator.next();

if (log.getPhonenumber() == phonenumber  && log.getType() == type && log.getDate() == date)
{
    updateLog(newLog, log .getId());
    ...
```

Every time you call `Iterator#next()`, it moves the underlying cursor forward.