# How to fix runtime error - Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

I'm getting the following error while trying to run my program. This is actually a submission for Hackerrank's "Day 6 Let's review" challenge.

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException   at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)     at
>   Solution.main(Solution.java:10)

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0; i<=T; i++){
        String S = sc.next();

        for(int j=0; j<S.length(); j++){
            if(j%2==0){
                System.out.print(S.charAt(j));
            }
        }

        System.out.print(" ");

        for(int r=0; r<S.length(); r++){
            if(r%2!=0){
                System.out.print(S.charAt(r));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0; i<=T; i++){
        if(!sc.hasNext()) break;
        String S = sc.next();

        for(int j=0; j<S.length(); j++){
            if(j%2==0){
                System.out.print(S.charAt(j));
            }
        }

        System.out.print(" ");

        for(int r=0; r<S.length(); r++){
            if(r%2!=0){
                System.out.print(S.charAt(r));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }
}
```

java.util.NoSuchElementException is thrown when there is no next element. To avoid this you should check by using hasNext().

Read this for more details : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnext.htm

Comment: Here is the docs for the exception : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html

Comment: Here is an already answered question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106753/java-util-nosuchelementexception-using-iterator-in-java

Comment: I think this is repeat but not sure

Answer (score 0):

You're code is perfectly fine.
There's no need to put a hasNext() method as you are not working with collections or arrays
I just tested your code, and it works well.
You error must be for something else